# Programming using socket for the first time. The connection is not happening.

Tags: c++, sockets, mfc

Please, this is the first time that I'm trying to program using sockets. I work with C++ MFC and I've tried to make an application to communicate with a video server controller by its TCP/IP address.

I make all the first steps without error. I create a socket, I call the `bind()` function to associate the address, but when I try to connect it doesn't work.

I don't know if I am doing something wrong, so I put part of my code bellow.

```
 struct sockaddr_in my_addr;
    int lenAddrs;

    b1 = 192;
    b2 = 168;
    b3 = 11;
    b4 = 2;

    remoteAddress.Format("%u.%u.%u.%u", b1, b2, b3, b4);

    port = (u_short)(portNumber);

    // my address
    memset(&my_addr, 0, sizeof(my_addr));
    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    my_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    lenAddrs = sizeof(my_addr);


    // remote address
    memset(&remote_addr, 0, sizeof(remote_addr));
    remote_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    remote_addr.sin_port = port;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, remoteAddress, (&remote_addr.sin_addr)); 

    // socket 
    sckSloMo = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (sckSloMo == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        AfxMessageBox("sckSloMo is invalid!!");
        return;
    }

    if (sckSloMo != SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        ret = bind(sckSloMo, (const sockaddr*) &my_addr, sizeof(my_addr));

        if (ret == 0)
        {
            ret = connect(sckSloMo, (const sockaddr*) &remote_addr, sizeof(remote_addr));
            if (ret == 0)
            {
                AfxMessageBox("connect!");
                StartSendingMessages();
            }
            else
            {
                AfxMessageBox("connect error!!!");
                return;
            }

        }
    }
```

If anybody could help me, I would be glad.

Comment: You are using the same `sockaddr` structure in `bind` and in `connect`. That doesn't make any sense. Generally, one doesn't call `bind` on a client socket. In `connect`, you pass the address of the server you want to connect **to**. I don't see where you spell out the destination IP address.

Comment: you don't need to use `bind`.  Have a look at [MSDN documentation for connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625(v=vs.85).aspx).  It would help if you provide the result of `WSAGetLastError()` when `connect` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
struct sockaddr_in remote_addr;
int lenAddrs;

b1 = 192;
b2 = 168;
b3 = 11;
b4 = 2;

remoteAddress.Format("%u.%u.%u.%u", b1, b2, b3, b4);

port = (u_short)(portNumber);

// remote address
memset(&remote_addr, 0, sizeof(remote_addr));
remote_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
remote_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
inet_pton(AF_INET, remoteAddress, (&remote_addr.sin_addr)); 

// socket 
sckSloMo = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

if (sckSloMo == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    AfxMessageBox("sckSloMo is invalid!!");
    return;
}

if (sckSloMo != SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    ret = connect(sckSloMo, (const sockaddr*) &remote_addr, sizeof(remote_addr));
    if (ret == 0)
    {
        AfxMessageBox("connect!");
        StartSendingMessages();
    }
    else
    {
        AfxMessageBox("connect error!!!");
        return;
    }
}
```

As someone else already, rightly pointed out, the value of the port is not in the right byte order.  Also, you do not need to use `bind()` on client-side sockets.  The [MSDN docuemntation for `connect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has an example that is quite straight forward and easy to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing things up. You need `bind()` for incoming sockets, not for outgoing sockets. You need connect for outgoing sockets, not for incoming sockets. So please only use connect, not `bind()`.

You are not initializing `remote_addr.sin_addr`. This won't work. If you do not explicitly initialize it, then it is still **0.0.0.0** from your memset(,0,). While **0.0.0.0** is perfect for a bind (meaning bind to all network cards), it is not a valid destination address for connect.

Sample code for setting `remote_addr.sin_addr`:

```
remote_addr.sin_addr = inet_addr("192.168.11.2");
```

Also, when putting the `port` into `sockaddr_in`, please don't forget to put it in the right byte order. Depending on the value of `port` you might need to change your code to:

```
remote_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
```

Comment: Hey, guys. I put the code with some changes that I tried to make. With these changes the error still happening. I don't know what can be causing this.